# node above rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to  make something like this
[image]

so far I have this

[image]

How can I make only one rectangle in the third row (0-8) and how can I write the numbers above the rectangles and only in the first rectangle a letter and colour the first rectangle grey?

This is my code

```
 \documentclass[titlepage=true, 12pt]{scrartcl}

    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}

    \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
    \setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0em}

    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}

    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[L]{Name}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}


    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

    \usepackage{setspace}

    \usepackage{tabularx}

    \usepackage{adjustbox}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

    \begin{document}

    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}

    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.63\textwidth}

    \begin{tabular}{|C{0.8cm}|L{8cm}|}

    \hline
    A & peu de cours \\
    \hline
    B &  la confiance en soi\\
    \hline
    C &  se trouve le village du Père Noël \\
    \hline
    D & début de semestre\\
    \hline
    E &  à augmenter la fréquentation de la ville\\
    \hline
    F & des ours polaires \\
    \hline
    G & fin de semestre\\
    \hline
    H & beaucoup de cours \\
    \hline
    I & nous a permis de nous intégrer plus facilement \\
    \hline
    J & une magnifique aurore boréale \\
    \hline
    K & les gens sont quasiment tous bilingues en anglais \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \end{minipage}}
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.36\textwidth}
    \def\m{40pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        square/.style={draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,minimum size=\m},
        outer sep=0,inner sep=0]
        \def\w{3}
        \def\h{3}

      \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}
        \foreach \y in {1,...,\h}
           {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{(\y-1) * \w + \x}
           \node [square]  (\x,\y) at (\x*\m,-\y*\m) {\label};
           }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}}


    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?  Short & sweet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine}
\newcommand\splat[3][white]{%
  \colorbox{#1}{~~\sffamily\stackon{\fbox{\makebox[3ex]{\large\strut #2}}}{#3}~~}%
}\begin{document}
\Shortstack[l]{
\splat[gray!20]{F}{0}\splat{}{1}\splat{}{2}\splat{}{3}
\splat{}{4}\splat{}{5}\splat{}{6}\splat{}{7}
\splat{}{8}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To ignore the nineth box, just check for `\label` being equal to 9.  To put the text above I use `label={above:\label}` and leave the node text empty.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}

\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.63\textwidth}

    \begin{tabular}{|C{0.8cm}|L{8cm}|}

      \hline
      A & peu de cours \\
      \hline
      B &  la confiance en soi\\
      \hline
      C &  se trouve le village du Père Noël \\
      \hline
      D & début de semestre\\
      \hline
      E &  à augmenter la fréquentation de la ville\\
      \hline
      F & des ours polaires \\
      \hline
      G & fin de semestre\\
      \hline
      H & beaucoup de cours \\
      \hline
      I & nous a permis de nous intégrer plus facilement \\
      \hline
      J & une magnifique aurore boréale \\
      \hline
      K & les gens sont quasiment tous bilingues en anglais \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}

  \end{minipage}}
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.36\textwidth}
    \def\m{40pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      square/.style={
        draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,minimum size=\m
      },
      outer sep=1pt,inner sep=0]
      \def\w{3}
      \def\h{3}

      \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}
        \foreach \y in {1,...,\h}
        {
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{(\y-1) * \w + \x}
          \ifnum\label=9\else
            \node [square,label={above:\label}] (\x,\y) at (\x*\m,-\y*\m) {};
          \fi
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How  can I fix the problem that the row ends with 3 and the next one starts with 3 instead of 4.

Answer (score 3):

I had to stretch it a bit, but you can use `label=[above:\label]`. You can remove the text inside of the nodes on your own.

[image: square]

```
 \documentclass[titlepage=true, 12pt]{scrartcl}

    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}

    \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
    \setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0em}

    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}

    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[L]{Name}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}


    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

    \usepackage{setspace}

    \usepackage{tabularx}

    \usepackage{adjustbox}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

    \begin{document}

    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}

    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.63\textwidth}

    \begin{tabular}{|C{0.8cm}|L{8cm}|}

    \hline
    A & peu de cours \\
    \hline
    B &  la confiance en soi\\
    \hline
    C &  se trouve le village du Père Noël \\
    \hline
    D & début de semestre\\
    \hline
    E &  à augmenter la fréquentation de la ville\\
    \hline
    F & des ours polaires \\
    \hline
    G & fin de semestre\\
    \hline
    H & beaucoup de cours \\
    \hline
    I & nous a permis de nous intégrer plus facilement \\
    \hline
    J & une magnifique aurore boréale \\
    \hline
    K & les gens sont quasiment tous bilingues en anglais \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \end{minipage}}
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.36\textwidth}
    \def\m{40pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        square/.style={draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,minimum size=\m},
        outer sep=0,inner sep=0]
        \def\w{3}
        \def\h{3}

      \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}
        \foreach \y in {1,...,\h}
           {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{(\y-1) * \w + \x}
           \node [square,label={[label distance=.1cm]above:\label}]  (\x,\y) at (\x*\m,-\y*\m*1.2) {\label};
           }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}}


    \end{document}
```